# How to find the source code for activity that currently displayed?

Tags: android

The situation: I should change design in activity that curently displayed on my phone. The problem is - how to find the source code for this activity, if I see this project at first time and there almost hundred activities and fragments and few hundreds of other classes.

Is there some way to see which activity running in the logcat? 
I'm using IntelliJ IDEA if it matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out: by default IntelliJ does not show messages from other packeges, but yes this information is present in the logcat. You should clear filter in logcat window and search for message from ActivityManager:

```
 I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed com.company/com.company.activities.MyActivity: +424ms
```